# Should I get a switch or second router for basement connections?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, switch

I currently have a modem/router combo on my main floor supporting 3 wireless connections.

I've run Cat5e to the basement from that device to my PC which was originally a 4 wireless connection to that device but the speeds were too slow for distance I was from it.

I now have several devices in the basement and need to connect them via Ethernet.

I've read that a 10/100/1000 switch may be the way to go as a second wireless router will not have its functionality used (since I am looking for wired connections).

**Question:**

Is the switch the best way to go or should I get a second router and turn off its wireless access point features?

Comment: A switch is by far the easiest, since it requires no configuration. A router will work, but you would need to set it up.

Answer (score 4):

Switches and routers serve two different purposes, though many routers can be configured to act like switches and many switches (particularly managed switches) can act like routers.

But the short answer to your question is that for a home network you're going to thank yourself for keeping it simple and using a switch instead of a router to extend your network. It saves you the hassle of having to do any configuration and you'll lose no desirable functionality.

The downside is that because consumer grade switches are sold in much lower volume than consumer grade routers, they tend to be more expensive.

Comment: But not a lot more expensive. I've used Netgear's stuff for a long time so checked on what I'm familiar with.  A 5-port gigabit switch goes for around $30. I'd expect some of the other suppliers to have similar units at similar prices. But decidedly +1 the idea of using a switch rather than a router.